# Inequality for locally Lipschitz continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Assume that function is locally Lipschitz continuous, i.e. 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x-y| \left(1+|x|^s+|y|^s\right)$$
for all $x \in R^m$ and some $L,s>0$. Then it should be true that 
$$\left|f(x) - f(y)\right| \leq M \left|x-y\right| \left(1+|x|^s\right) + M|x-y|^{s+1}.$$
However I cannot see a way to prove it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The "continuous" is redundent with how you define locally Lipschitz. I thought that locally Lipschitzmeant : for each $x\in\mathbf{R}^m$ there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that the restriction $f|_V$ of $f$ to $V$ is Lipschitz. Do I miss something obvious ?

Comment: I think both definitions are equivalent when the function is defined on the whole $R^m$, [see this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162025/are-those-locally-lipschitz-definitions-equivalent). The "continuous" is probably redundant I am just reading an article, where they use is instead of simply Lipschitz.

Comment: What is this quoted question shows the equivalence ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly the quoted question, more precisely Christians answer show the equivalence of two definitions: 

$f$ is locally Lipschitz, when for each $x$ there exist neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f|_V$ is Lipschitz, 

a definition>

Comment: If I understand it correctly the quoted question, more precisely Christians answer show the equivalence of two definitions, **first definition**: 

$f$ is locally Lipschitz, when for each $x$ there exist neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f|_V$ is Lipschitz, 

and **second definition**:

$f$ is locally Lipschitz, when there exist function positive function $l(.)$ such that $\forall x,y$ $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq l(|x|+|y|)|x-y|$$ 

And the equivalence between this definition and my definition seems to be obvious. Sorry for multiple posting.

Comment: $l$ is a function, not a constant... $l(|x|+|y|)$ means the value of the function $l$ at the point $|x|+|y|$. It does not mean "the constant $l$ times $|x|+|y|$. See all comment of the question you've linked to. Again : your definition is not equivalent to being locally Lipschitz.

Comment: I know that $l$ is a function. If my inequality (not really my, taken from [sec. 2.2](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00409060/document) ) hold than one can define $l(t) = \max\{1+|x|^s+|y|^s;|x|+|y|=t\}$ so the function $f$ is locally Lipschitz. On the other hand if $f$ is locally Lipschitz and function $l$ exist, I am not sure that $s$ satisfying my inequality exists. I thought that it was clear but I will definitely have to think about it more. Thank you for all your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case I: suppose  that $|y| < 2|x-y|$. Then $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le L|x-y|(1+|x|^s) + 2^s L|x-y|^{1+s}.$$
Case II: suppose that $|y| \ge 2|x-y|$.  Then $$|y| \le |x| + |x-y| \le |x| + \frac 12 |y|$$
so that $$|y| \le 2|x|$$ and thus $$(1 + |x|^s + |y|^s) \le (1 + 2^s)(1 + |x|^s)$$ and $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le (1+2^s)L |x-y| (1 + |x|^s).$$

Comment: Thank you. Ashamed, that I did not see it.